# Hiding Inactive Menubar Items

Tags: macos, settings, icon, menu-bar

I am curious if there is a way for me to hide certain objects in the menubar when they are "inactive." Some examples:

- Bluetooth hides when Bluetooth is off
- Wifi hides when wifi is off
- Audio/sound hides when sound is muted
- Battery hides when it is 100% charged

These are some examples. I use Alfred Workflows to work with these objects most of the time so having them in my menubar sometimes is useful but sometimes isn't. I use Bartender but was unable to find this option within it's settings. Admittedly, this is a pretty esoteric question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice tutorial on the various options and techniques here: http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/customization/customizing-the-os-x-menu-bar/

None of these is quite as flexible as you ask for (Wifi hides when wifi is off...), but realize that the majority of those icons are controls as well as indications. For example, if the wifi is off, the icon can be used to access the wifi controls. This can be real handy to turn the wifi back on. ;-) Hiding the icon would make that a more lengthy process, forcing you to go through the settings app.

Comment: How would I go through this settings app? I don't need to icons to turn on the controls as I have keyboard shortcuts to turn on or off these various items.